# How do I persist my columns automatically with JPA

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a table in which I have previously inserted data using JPA. However now I want to remove the column from db. I am using Postgres SQL. I have kept the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` config as update. Yet upon removing a field from the entity the values from that column only becomes null. How do I manage to delete the column from the table?

Comment: Do it in SQL : drop column

Comment: yes, but can JPA handle it automatically?

Comment: I don't think so.